# how to solve this problem error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I am trying to install pyroms (https://github.com/ESMG/pyroms) 
I am using python 3.6 
when I write the "python setup.py build" 
I get this error message:
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this error occurs when in your PATH somebody cannot locate vcvars.bat. This comes with Microsoft SDK. Double check that you have rge SDK installed (whatever version). Alternatively, you can try to manually invoke the "visual studio xxx command prompt"  (where xxxi the architecture you are running the program. This is found in the program files start menu, after installing the SDK) and then invoke your software.
Usually these steps solve the issue.